# React/redux - passing actionCreators many levels deep

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm wondering how other people are handling passing redux action creators from a smart top-level component down to many lower level dumb components without bloating their props definitions.

For example, following [this excellent tutorial on redux](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html#the-client-application), if I pass a list of action creators into the props like so

```
import Voting from './Voting';
import * as actionCreators from '../action_creators';

...

export const VotingContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    actionCreators
)(Voting);
```

then in my Voting component I have access to the actionCreators which is really cool.

But if I have say 20 actionCreators that are used in Voting and all of its child components, eg.

```
Voting -> VotingContainer -> VotingDetail -> VotingFoo -> VotingBar
```

then I end up with render functions that look like this

```
class Voting extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <VotingContainer
            actionCreator1={this.props.actionCreator1}
            .
            .
            .
            actionCreator15={this.props.actionCreator15} />
    }
}

class VotingContainer extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <VotingDetail
            actionCreator1={this.props.actionCreator1}
            .
            .
            .
            actionCreator12={this.props.actionCreator12} />
    }
}

.
.
.

class VotingFoo extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <VotingBar
            actionCreator1={this.props.actionCreator1}
            .
            .
            .
            actionCreator6={this.props.actionCreator6} />
    }
}
```

Is there a best practice for this situation, a way to group the actionCreators together somehow without a lot of boilerplate at each step ? I haven't seen anything in any of the tutorials/examples...

Comment: Do you really need 20 action creators for each component, or are you automatically passing more props that a component needs?

Comment: No it's more like I have 20 action creators that I have to spread around among 20 child components of the top-level one

Comment: Plus other props that are not action creators

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just connect components below the tree to Redux too.
We over-emphasize “one container at the top” in the examples.
This makes sense when we’re talking about very simple apps.

For any complex app, **as soon as passing props gets tedious, `connect()` components below.**
I cover this in my free videos: see [Extracting Container Components](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-extracting-container-components-filterlink?series=getting-started-with-redux) and the next several videos.

Comment: ok thanks that makes sense ! i knew there must be something i was missing

Comment: Does this mean that for complex app, as soon as passing props gets tedious, the component should become a Smart Component instead of a Dumb Component?

Comment: @Seeya Yeah, more or less. It means you need to create a container for your presentational component. Please see my screencasts: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-extracting-container-components-visibletodolist-addtodo and next several videos.

Comment: @DanAbramov but what about reusability of components?

For example, I have this structure
Grandparent -> Parent -> Child -> NestedChild
and NestedChild need to dispatch an action in store.

I can pass all necessary actions from the grandparent, but in this case all components in the middle (Parent, Child) will know about actions for the NestedChild. And it's not good, as you've pointed out in your videos.

And I can't create smart "container component" to provide action dispatch since it will make GrandParent component not reusable - type of action is depending on data passed to GrandParent.

Comment: It very much depends on the situation. Hard to say with such abstract terms. Don’t forget `GrandParent` doesn’t *have* to be reusable. You can extract the reusable parts from it into separate components. You can pass `children` to it. There are many ways to componentize.

Comment: my fault - instead of "it will make GrandParent component not reusable " should be "it will make NestedChild component not reusable ". Yes, GrandParent will not be reusable

Comment: Same here. It does not *have* to be reusable. If there is valuable part of NestedChild that contains DOM markup or logic that might be useful independently, *extract that* into a presentational component. **I don’t suggest turning presentational components into containers. I suggest creating a container component that *wraps* a presentational component.** In fact you can create many different containers wrapping the same presentational component.

Comment: Hi Dan, what do you think about my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856656/react-redux-passing-actioncreators-many-levels-deep#answer-52758326) ?

Answer (score 0):

I find that in most cases where I have a lot of dumb wrappers around a core ui component, most of the props from the top container are needed in the most nested component.
Because of this, ES6 ... syntax helps a lot.

You can do this:

```
<VotingBar {...this.props} />
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
<VotingBar
    actionCreator1={this.props.actionCreator1}
    .
    .
    .
    actionCreator6={this.props.actionCreator6} />
```

Comment: I have used this sometimes, but the problem comes when I have several core ui components under one top-level smart component. Then I have the choice of passing *everything* to every dumb component all the way down (which is not very performant I imagine) or having to deal with these masses of prop definitions...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid passing propertied from level to level down to where those props are actually used, [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) could be used to wrap the top Child with context (some specific data).

#### [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/5d1c911bed172d93fcebf649a75fd489?editors=0010)

Here's a simple use-case example, where more than one reducer is defined, each of the reducers is responsible for its own state (a counter in this example)

A `<Button>` is inside a `<Modal>` and two *Modal* components are inside *App*, each one should eventually "broadcast" the change made internally (in the deepest component) to the top component (*App*) which is actually listening to the changes and acting on them.

Only *App* cares about changes in *Button* but since there can be many *Button* components, the *App* must know which deep component did what action and dispatch the right data back to **Redux**.

The *Modal* is simply something in between which exists for representational purposes only. it doesn't care about any props or state. *Button* also doesn't care about anything except what is being sent to it directly via the Context. he listen to changes via the `Consumer` method from `React.createContext`

```js
const { Provider:ContextProvider, Consumer:ContextConsumer } = React.createContext({});
const {connect, Provider } = ReactRedux; 
const {createStore, compose, combineReducers} = Redux; 
const {Component} = React; 

//// REDUX STORE STUFF /////////////////////////////////////
function reducer_foo(state = {value:1}, action){
  if( action.type == 'FOO__SET_VALUE') // type should be unique
    return { ...state, value:action.value }
  else return state
}

function reducer_bar(state = {value:1}, action){
  if( action.type == 'BAR__SET_VALUE') // type should be unique
    return { ...state, value:action.value }
  else return state
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foo: reducer_foo,
  bar: reducer_bar
});

//// REACT STUFF /////////////////////////////////////

// 2nd depth-level
// This component's "job" is to simply take a value and return a manipulated value to
// whoever called it. This is a very simplifed component, but think of a datepicker instead.
const Button = () =>
  <ContextConsumer>
      {v => <button onClick={()=> v.action(v.value + 1, v.name)}>Click to INC: {v.value}</button>}
  </ContextConsumer>



// 1st depth-level (in reality this level will be more complex)
const Modal = () => <p><Button /></p>



// top depth-level component
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  
  // The deepest component will pass the value and the name for which to dispatch to
  updateValue = ( value, name ) => {
    this.props.dispatch({type:`${name.toUpperCase()}__SET_VALUE`, value})
  }
  
  render(){
    const {foo, bar} = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ContextProvider value={{value:foo.value, action:this.updateValue, name:'foo'}}>
          <Modal />
        </ContextProvider>
        
        <ContextProvider value={{value:bar.value, action:this.updateValue, name:'bar'}}>
          <Modal />
        </ContextProvider>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state){
  return state // in this example let's just pass the whole state for simplicity
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.7/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are of course a variety of ways you can tackle this issue.

Recently, I've started skipping the whole passing of action creator functions down the chain in favor of **just requiring the store and my action creators directly wherever they're needed** and dispatching from there, e.g.

```
var store = require('../store');
var actions = require('../actions');

// Somewhere inside your component...
store.dispatch(actions.someAction(data));
```

Just make sure the *result* of your action creators (i.e. the new state) is passed down through your top level components.  This keeps your data flow unidirectional and easy to understand.

Comment: if you need to dispatch a particular action, it would be better to create a Container component and connect to the store using `connect` in React-Redux

Comment: Why?  Both methods accomplish the exact same thing with the exact same level of transparency -- one approach (mine) just requires less boilerplate and doesn't touch props.  I generally prefer to only `connect` higher level components that need to know about state, not random lower level components that **don't** need to know about state and just dispatch actions (e.g. a button).

Comment: This approach uses a single store instance exposed by `../store`. This means that this code can't work on the server side where you need a separate store instance for each request to ensure you don't expose data of  one client to another.

Exposing a store instance also makes it difficult to customize the store depending on the context. It is preferred to expose a `createStore` function which allows passing of middleware for example.