# How to response to change of specific state in redux?

Tags: redux

Now the Component can only know the global `state` has changed, but cannot determine which state is actually changed. Here is my scenario:

`Component Root --- very deep --- Component Leaf`

`Component Leaf` is very deep in the component hierarchy, it triggers an action, change global state, and `Component Root` want to change some inner state in response to this action. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you'll find this isn't the correct way to think about it:

> `Component Root` want to change some inner state in response to this action

When using Redux and React, anything derived from the store should be *props* not state.

So firstly, convert the aforementioned state into props.

Secondly, set those props using the `connect` function from `react-redux`.

You've probably seen something like this in the Redux docs:

```
// Take the store state and return the props for your root component
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Root);
```

How you define your mapStateToProps function is up to you. You can choose to use all or part of the state.

Finally, pass the relevant props down the hierarchy to the `Leaf` node.

Don't worry too much about which part of the state has changed. It's the job of React and Redux to restrict the rendering solely to the changed components. Just make sure to avoid mutating the state in your reducers.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Abramov, the creator of redux, [recommends connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861969/788260) deeper components with the redux `@connect` as soon as passing props becomes tedious.

If you follow the advice of keeping components split up by [smart and dumb](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.7i8abon1h) (I like to call them containers and components), in which smart components collect data and dumb components display it, then you can connect any smart components no matter how deep.